# ARKit SCNTechnique multi pass rendering

Tags: swift, arkit, metal

I'm trying to implement a filter using an SCNTechnique for an ARKit scene.

The idea is that I want to apply a filter on a scene (grayscale) and ignore some of the nodes that are added the the ARKit scene. I've managed to add a pass using a Metal shader using `DRAW_QUAD` on the whole scene and other passthrough `DRAW_SCENE` pass that renders the nodes using `includeCategoryMask`.

I'm not sure how I should chain these two. If I apply the DRAW_SCENE, then DRAW_QUAD, the filter is applied to the node I'm trying to mask out, the other way around nothing happens.

I don't have much experience in Metal, so I'm curious on how should I approach the problem. If needed, I can also provide some source code.